# Is is possible to get additional information about the appstate?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I would like to know if there is a way to get additional information about the appstate? I'm using React Native and I looked at the documentation for AppState (https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) but I need more information than just 'active', 'inactive' or 'background'.

For example if the user would lock the phone I would need to get something like 'locked' or when the user gets a call when using the app I get back 'call'. Is something like this possible in React Native (or other programming languages)?

Comment: There is no single equivalent for all that, because there is no "app state" concept in Android.  So you'd need to be very specific about what you want.  It used to be possible to know when the screen went off (the locked state), but I don't think it generally is anymore.  You can get the call state natively, although probably only if your app is active.  However these are all going to need to be hooked up separately, and they aren't exclusive-  you can be locked and in a call for example.

Comment: Hmm I see, so I would need to use Swift or Kotlin for this.

Comment: Probably.  You might be able to use a native module to do it, as long as you don't need to be notified of state changes (just be able to get the current state).  Of course that would be something you need to code on both iOS and Android, unless you can find someone who's already done the work.

Comment: I don't think anyone has. The app that I'm building needs to stay active, as in the user can't leave the app. They can close the phone, but not leave the app. This is the problem since leaving the app and closing the phone both resolve in the appstate background.

Comment: Then what you want on Android is  a launcher app.  A launcher app replaces the home app.  It could theoretically have a ReactNative UI, although that would be uncommon.  Assuming this is only going to run on hardware you own (otherwise this requirement makes no sense), combined with Android Enterprise you can lock it down pretty hard.  But at this point you're going to be doing a significant amount of work in native and on iOS and Android separately in setting it up.